# Detecting when an iframe gets or loses focus

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

What's the correct way of detecting when an iframe gets or loses focus (i.e. will or will not receive keyboard events)? The following is not working in Fx4:

```
var iframe = /* my iframe */;
iframe.addEventListener("focus", function() { /* never gets called */ }, false);
```

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926861/iframe-onblur-event

Comment: @Uw I have no control on the contents of the iframe (different origin) and that method requires accessing iframe.contentDocument (not allowed for documents coming from a different origin)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out it's not really possible. I had to change the logic of my page to avoid the need of tracking if the iframe has focus.

Comment: It is possible.  See my answer.

Comment: The answers given is possible with cross-origin if you implement HTML5 sendMessage to talk between the two

Answer (score 28):

You can poll "document.activeElement" to determine if it matches the iframe.  Polling isn't ideal, but it works:

```
function checkFocus() {
  if(document.activeElement == document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0]) {
    console.log('iframe has focus');
  } else {
    console.log('iframe not focused');
  }
}

window.setInterval(checkFocus, 1000);
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I'm using chromium on a page with an embedded youtube video. Clicking the video doesn't change document.activeElement, which always point to the main window's <body>

Comment: It works in a plain iframe; not sure what the embedded YouTube video does. When you click on it, it might use javascript to set the focus somewhere else.  It might even be using Flash.

Comment: I tested later with chrome. Indeed I get different behaviours in Chrome x Chromium. In Chrome it works as you say. In chromium, it works as I stated above.

Comment: this was the only way i was able to prevent the [youtube iframe](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) from stealing focus when player.nextVideo() was called

Comment: @Ryan Great ! It works too with cross-origin website. In my opinon, it is a violation to CSP because we shouldn't be able to get if we click in a iframe. With this, we can guess when occurs the first click into iframe.

Comment: I had problems with Safari and document.activeElement. It probably works as expected only with input elements, not iframe.

Answer (score 12):

i know it's old, but i also had the same problem.

i ended up using this little pice of code:

```
$(document).on('focusout', function(){
       setTimeout(function(){
       // using the 'setTimout' to let the event pass the run loop
       if (document.activeElement instanceof HTMLIFrameElement) {
             // Do your logic here..
        }
    },0);
});
```

Comment: did not work for [youtube iframe](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Mobile_considerations). when I called player.nextVideo(), the iframe stole the focus without calling this method

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. The timeout thingy was essential as I was trying to hide a dropdown element when the user clicked anywhere using a simple window click event which actually does not fire when you change focus to an iframe (like tinymce uses). This focusout and timeout ensures that I can close the popup as well make sure whatever I clicked inside the popup is also fired.

Comment: Great solution. Thanks!

Comment: Very nice solution! You need to note in your answer that `focusout` will be triggered on several DOM elements not only on Iframes (textarea, inputs etc).

Answer (score 4):

## How to check when an iframe has been clicked in or out of as well as hover-state.

**Note**: I would highly recommend you don't choose a polling method and go with an event driven method such as this.

---

### Disclaimer

It is not possible to use the `focus` or `blur` events directly on an iframe but you can use them on the `window` to provide an event driven method of checking the `document.activeElement`. Thus you can accomplish what you're after.

Although we're now in 2018, my code is being implemented in GTM and tries to be cross browser compatible back to IE 11. This means there's more efficient code if you're utilizing newer ES/ECMAScript features.

---

### Setup

I'm going to take this a few steps further to show that we can also get the iframe's `src` attribute as well as determine if it's being hovered.

#### Code

You would ideally need to put this in a document ready event, or at least encapsulate it so that the variables aren't global [maybe use an IIFE]. I did not wrap it in a document ready because it's handled by GTM. It may also depend where you place this or how you're loading it such as in the footer.

https://jsfiddle.net/9285tbsm/9/

I have noticed in the JSFiddle preview that it's already an iframe, sometimes you have to focus it first before events start to capture. Other issues can be that your browser window isn't yet focused either.

```
// Helpers

var iframeClickedLast;

function eventFromIframe(event) {
  var el = event.target;
  return el && el.tagName && el.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'iframe';
}

function getIframeSrc(event) {
  var el = event.target;
  return eventFromIframe(event) ? el.getAttribute('src') : '';
}

// Events

function windowBlurred(e) {
  var el = document.activeElement;
  if (el.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'iframe') {
    console.log('Blurred: iframe CLICKED ON', 'SRC:', el.getAttribute('src'), e);
    iframeClickedLast = true;
  } 
  else {
    console.log('Blurred', e);
  }
}

function windowFocussed(e) {
  if (iframeClickedLast) {
    var el = document.activeElement;
    iframeClickedLast = false;
    console.log('Focussed: iframe CLICKED OFF', 'SRC:', el.getAttribute('src'), e);
  } 
  else {
    console.log('Focussed', e);
  }
}

function iframeMouseOver(e) {
  console.log('Mouse Over', 'SRC:', getIframeSrc(e), e);
}

function iframeMouseOut(e) {
  console.log('Mouse Out', 'SRC:', getIframeSrc(e), e);
}

// Attach Events

window.addEventListener('focus', windowFocussed, true);  
window.addEventListener('blur', windowBlurred, true);

var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
for (var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
  iframes[i].addEventListener('mouseover', iframeMouseOver, true);
  iframes[i].addEventListener('mouseout', iframeMouseOut, true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Just one thing: The focus detection inside the windowBlurred function worked for me only in WebKit and Chromium Browsers, but not in Firefox, because Firefox seems to update the activeElement only *after* firing the blur event. My solution is that the blur listener does not directly execute the windowBlurred function, but uses window.setTimeout(windowBlurred, 0) instead.

Comment: Your code was ineffectual in Firefox.  Investigation revealed that focus and blur events only get fired on the outer window.  mouseover and mouseout on the outer window work, although this alone doesn't tell if the iframe got focused.  I tried using mousedown on the outer window, but this too only fires for events on the outer window.

Answer (score 3):

I have solved this by using `contentWindow` instead of `contentDocument`.
The good thing about `contentWindow` is

1. it works also in case user clicks another window (another application) or another browser tab. If using `activeElement`, if user clicks away from the entire window to go to another application, then that logic still think the iframe is in focus, while it is not
2. and we don't need to poll and do a `setInterval` at all. This uses the normal `addEventListener`

```
let iframe = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
// or whatever way you do to grab that iFrame, say you have an `id`, then it's even more precise
if(iframe){
  iframeWindow = iframe.contentWindow;
  iframeWindow.addEventListener('focus', handleIframeFocused);
  iframeWindow.addEventListener('blur', handleIframeBlurred);
}

function handleIframeFocused(){
  console.log('iframe focused');
  // Additional logic that you need to implement here when focused
}

function handleIframeBlurred(){
  console.log('iframe blurred');
  // Additional logic that you need to implement here when blurred
}
```

Comment: Thanks it's cleaner and works better than the most upvoted answers.

Comment: This won't work on iframes that reference foreign content: SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is working for me on both mobile and desktop:

```
;(function pollForIframe() {
  var myIframe = document.querySelector('#my_iframe');
  if (!myIframe) return setTimeout(pollForIframe, 50);

  window.addEventListener('blur', function () {
    if (document.activeElement == myIframe) {
      console.log('myIframe clicked!');
    }
  });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to inject a javascript event on the parent page like this :

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';

script.innerHTML = 
"document.addEventListener('click', function()" + 
"{ if(document.getElementById('iframe')) {" +
    // What you want
"}});"; 

head.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: As I wrote above in my answer to Uw, I have no control on the contents of the iframe (different origin). This obviously means I can't inject anything either from parent to children or from children to parent.

Comment: Sorry dude, so it will be more complicated in this can you need to by-pass the cross domain problem dude...

All lot of solution exist but it's not very clean...

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the code to Detecting when an iframe gets or loses focus**

```js
// This code can be used to verify Iframe gets focus/loses.

function CheckFocus(){
    if (document.activeElement.id == $(':focus').context.activeElement.id) {
        // here do something
    } else {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean that "this code fires"? There are no events handlers, that's just an if... As it is I can't imagine how this is supposed to work, please provide a codepen or similar that shows that it works.

Comment: this code fires means: This code can be used inside any event or function to verify element is focused or blur.It's simple. We have modified the code for better understanding.

Comment: Sure thanks, but that's not what the question was about. The question asks how to detect, i.e. receive a notification. Your solution does not send a notification, it requires polling for the state.

Answer (score 0):

A compact function that accepts callbacks you want to run when iframe gets or loses focus.

```js
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
export default function watchIframeFocus(onFocus, onBlur) {
  let iframeClickedLast;

  function windowBlurred(e) {
    const el = document.activeElement;
    if (el.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'iframe') {
      iframeClickedLast = true;
      onFocus();
    } 
  }
  function windowFocussed(e) {
    if (iframeClickedLast) {
      iframeClickedLast = false;
      onBlur();
    } 
  }
  window.addEventListener('focus', windowFocussed, true);  
  window.addEventListener('blur', windowBlurred, true);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This might work

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var frame= document.getElementById("yourFrameID");

  var isClickInsideFrame = frame.contains(event.target);

  if (!isClickInsideFrame ) {
    //exec code
  }

});
```

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't work with different domains (CORS). for example:
https://jsfiddle.net/liadmagen/bxhwv9v1/1/