# How can I capture the onfocus event of child iframes?

Tags: javascript, iframe, onfocus

`window.onfocus` is not getting fired when the focus is on a child `iframe`.

I'm looking for an event which will be fired when the user is switching the tab to current page. (If possible without modifying child iframes)

Comment: @RaulGogo [The question title shouldn't contain any tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/206447).

Comment: blur event should be what you're after

Comment: @Tivie: I don't understand how blur can be useful for that. Can you please explain?

Comment: @Dukeling: I should be ashamed of not knowing that. My bad. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: focus event is when an element is gaining focus, blur is when an element is loosing focus. You asked for an event that will be fired when the user is switching. That event is blur

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456239/detecting-when-an-iframe-gets-or-loses-focus

Comment: and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369026/setting-focus-to-iframe-contents

Comment: and this one which links to a post outside SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926861/iframe-onblur-event

Comment: @Tivie: I want to know when the user switches to the tab where my app is open, he might have switched from a tab with facebook, gmail, etc. It could be anything, I can't track onblur of other sites.

Comment: AH, you mean actual browser tabs, not the TAB key. My mistake.

Comment: even so, the links I posted are relevant. Is your iframe and your main page on the same domain?