# Iframe Click Event works Only Once after Page load Javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am trying to get user click event from an Iframe. For this I have written below Javascript code, Problem is only first click works after page load. I need to fire this on every click. how to do this

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var clickIframe = window.setInterval(checkFocus, 100);
 var i = 0;

 function checkFocus() {
  if(document.activeElement == document.getElementById("pgl")) {
  console.log("clicked "+(i++));
  alert("i am clicked");
  window.focus();
  }
}  
</script>
```

This is the iframe

```
 <iframe src="https://www.neobux.com/" id="pgl" name="pgl" class="surfer_frame" frameborder="0" onmouseover="on_mouseover(this)" onmouseout="on_mouseout(this)">
</iframe>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML too? We need to know what the element with `id=“pgl”` is. At a glance, your script only works once because the click takes focus from that element.

Comment: pgl is the id of iframe i have edited my question

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working version of what you have. (Which I suspect came from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12979139/14956277).)

The `activeElement` is queried once per second and an alert is shown if the iframe is active.

```js
// Initialize the counter.
var checkCounter = 0;

// Declare the function before assigning it as a callback.
function checkFocus()
{
    // Get the current minute and second as a timestamp.
    let timeStamp = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", { minute: "2-digit", second: "2-digit" });

    // Output the timestamp and currently active element to the results box.
    outputArea.value += "[" + timeStamp + "] Active element: " + document.activeElement + "\n";
    
    // Try to alert if the iframe is active.
    try {
        if (document.activeElement == document.getElementById("pgl")) {
            outputArea.value += "\tiframe is active for check number " + ++checkCounter + ".\n";
            
            // Prevent more than four alerts so the page isn't locked.
            if (checkCounter < 4)
            {
                outputArea.value += "\tAlerting.\n";
                alert("I am clicked");
            }
            else {
                outputArea.value += "\tNot alerting - more than 4 attempts.\n";
            }
        }
    }
    catch (e) {
    
      // Show the error.
      outputArea.value += "\tUnable to alert. Error: " + e.substring(0, 20) + "...\n";
    }
    
    // Scroll to the bottom of the results box.
    outputArea.scrollTop = outputArea.scrollHeight;
}

var outputArea = document.getElementById("output-area");
var clickFrame = window.setInterval(checkFocus, 1000);
```

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 16px;
}

code {
  color: darkgray;
}

#pgl, #output-area {
  width: 90%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  
  <h1>Click the frame to trigger an alert:</h1>
  <iframe src="https://example.com" 
          id="pgl"></iframe>
  
  <h1>Log of <code>clickFrame</code> activity:</h1>
  <textarea id="output-area"></textarea>

</body>
```