# Getting stats about the downloads of an episode from buzzsprout API and push it to dataLayer as an event

Tags: javascript, api

We have a site and it contains the audio player containers for every episode (podcast service is 'buzzsprout'). The containers are in iFrame. I'd like to push to datalayer an event every time the user clicks 'play'. I need this info to sent to analytics system.

The Buzzsprout API gives just the info about the 'total_plays' and the 'title' (the name of the episode).

My idea is:

1. send the request to buzzsprout to get the info about the episode when the page with the episodes are loaded and save the resource;
2. send the request to buzzsprout when the user has interacted with the iframe to check if the resource is changed (we are interested in 'total_plays' metric) if the resource is changed that will mean the user has clicked 'play' button;
3. If so we send the data to dataLayer object:

   ```
    dataLayer.push({
            event: 'download',
            download: {
              name: 'title'
            }
    });
   ```

Is this idea real or might anybody give some tips for me and our dev? Thank you!

Comment: How do you intend to determine _“when the user has interacted with the iframe”_? You usually can’t do that with 3rd-party iframes - unless the provider explicitly provides you with a JS API for such purposes, that can handle the necessary cross origin communication.

Comment: _“check if the resource is changed (we are interested in 'total_plays' metric)”_ - does that even get updated in real time to begin with? Most such services probably cache such stats, for performance reasons.

Comment: @CBroe 
1) we could determine the interaction with the iframe with the approach described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456239/detecting-when-an-iframe-gets-or-loses-focus
It works fine with interactions with such buttons as 'Add to Apple Wallet' in iFrames as and example. 
2) As for updating the info from buzzsprout in real-time you are right. We are not able to get this info right away, unfortunately. I tested it. Looks that the only way is to use buzzsprout dashboard to track the stats.
Thank you!